# GUI to update a destination excel file with external data excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter, openpyxl

I'm stuck trying to develop a GUI that simply import a directory of an excel file (new data) then when I click a button, the command function is to amend the information on this (new data) excel file into the maximum row of a (source data) excel file.

I used the dataframe and .amend method after converting the two excel sheets to a data frame. However, this might not be good, the (new data) excel might come up with no heading orders like the source data file to amend the information.

Any help?

```
## Import function to amend data from a sheet to an existing resource sheet
def importdata():

    df1 = pd.read_excel('Destiny.xlsx', index_col=0)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(fileroot, index_col=0)
    df1.append(df2, ignore_index= True)
    df1 = df1.append(df2)
    Saveit = df1.to_excel('Destiny.xlsx')
    importbtn.config(text='Imported', command= NONE, bg='grey')
```

Comment: Instead of `command="none", bg="grey"` you might want to use `state="disabled"` if you don't want the user to be able to press the button

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks, this is good notice.